# Release on an running Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How can I know the release of a running liferay? Is there any file to check somewhere?

I tried to check dome of the readme files but didn"t find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Control Panel -> Server Administration, there the version will be displayed:

[image: Liferay control panel]

Another option is to check (grep) `$LIFERAY_HOME/logs/liferay.yyyy-mm-dd.log` which reports the version number during startup:

```
08:49:06,691 INFO  [fileinstall-C:/liferay70/osgi/marketplace][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED Liferay CE Foundation_7.0.7 [174]
```

Comment: If the log mentioning 7.0.7 is taken from a currently running installation, it's the version of that module, not the full release (As of today Liferay CE is at 7.0.2) - Due to semantic versioning of the modules both have nothing to do with each other. There's another line containing the actual release in the log somewhere though. Note that Enterprise Edition doesn't necessarily give away the fixpack/service pack this way as those keep the version stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change the http.header.version.verbosity=full
 the liferay version it is being shown on the response headers.

Below is the info about this property, from portal.properties on liferay sources.

```
#
# Set the level of verbosity to use for the Liferay-Portal field in the HTTP
# header response. Valid values are "full", which gives all of the version
# information (e.g. Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE etc.),
# "partial", which gives only the name portion (e.g. Liferay Portal
# Community Edition), or the default release name (e.g. "Liferay Portal
# Community Edition" or "Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition"), which prevents
# the Portal from adding the Liferay-Portal field in the HTTP header
# response. The default release name must match the Portal edition being
# used.
#
http.header.version.verbosity=full
```

Hope this helps